# Access external server file with php script which are only downloaded by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, file

I need to access an external server file in my php script.

However the file path is not visible. This is because external site use JavaScript functions to call the file download.

How can I access such files in my php script?

Comment: Switch to developer mode in your browser and see which requests are happening.

Comment: It call a javascript function which calls an asp.net form submit